# how to declare a reference to a struct

Tags: assembly, struct, x86-16, masm

I'm using MASM 5 (very old I know, sorry). I have a struct `foo` defined:

```
FOO STRUCT
  bar DB ?
FOO ENDS

foo FOO {}
```

In my program I am passing the offset to `foo` to another module in the `bx` register:

```
mov bx,OFFSET foo
call func
```

In my other module I am now receiving the offset of `foo` in the `bx` register. I want to store this reference in a module level defined variable so I can reference it as a struct:

```
foo PRT FOO ; not correct :(

func PROC NEAR
  mov foo,bx
  mov foo.bar, 0
func ENDP
```

How can I define `foo` as a reference to `FOO` in the module?

Comment: Not sure you can do that. What you should be able to do is `ASSUME bx:PTR FOO` (inside `func`), and then you could do things like `mov [bx].bar, 0`. Then reset the assumption with `ASSUME bx:NOTHING`.

Comment: Is `foo PRT FOO` supposed to be `PTR`, not `PRT`?  I don't know MASM syntax, dunno if `PRT` is a thing like short for "prototype"...  (Or if changing it would help.)

Comment: Wait a minute, if you get a pointer to the struct in `bx`, then `mov foo, bx` would mean the memory at `foo` holds a pointer, not a struct.  What do you want `mov foo.bar, 0` to assemble to?  **x86 doesn't have memory-indirect addressing modes.**  If you want to store to the pointed-to struct, the struct address already needs to be in a register.  The only way `mov foo.bar, 0` was if `foo` *was* a struct, not a pointer to a struct.  I don't know MASM's struct syntax, but it would have to be something like `mov [bx + FOO.bar], 0` to be usable.  Some syntax for BX + offsetof(FOO, bar).

Comment: @PeterCordes AFAIK the explicit syntax would be `mov (FOO PTR [bx]).bar, 0`. Or you can make a temporary assumption of `bx` holding the address of a `FOO` as I mentioned in my previous comment.